# Java Set local file Hyperlink in existing pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf, hyperlink, itext

I am trying to provide a hyper link in a existing PDF, which when clicked will open the file. How can this be done?

I have try following Code it work fine for external hyper link like **http://www.google.com**  but not working for local file hyperlink like **D:/intro.pdf** .

i am using **itext pdf library.**

Code :

```
        String in = "D:/introduction.pdf";
        String out = "D:/introduction.pdf";

        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);


            PdfContentByte canvas=stamper.getOverContent(6);
            Chunk imdb = new Chunk("Local Link");
            imdb.setAnchor("http://www.google.com"); // this work
         // imdb.setAnchor("D://intro.pdf");  // this does not work

            ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(imdb), 100, 10, 0);



            stamper.close();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(out);


            IOUtils.write(baos.toByteArray(), fileOutputStream);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

i have also try using Annotation as below :

```
                PdfAnnotation annotation;

                PdfName aa=new PdfName("test test");
                annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
                        new Rectangle(50f, 750f, 180f, 800f),aa,PdfAction.gotoRemotePage("file:///D:/intro.pdf","1", false, true));


                annotation.setTitle("Click Here");

                stamper.addAnnotation(annotation, 1);
```

I have also try below code comment by @**Bruno Lowagie** : [ it create link on given page but in intro.pdf file and when i click on link it on same page (intro.pdf)]
[image: see in below image]
as per above image ( image of **intro.pdf page number-2** )

```
                PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader("D://introduction.pdf");
                PdfStamper stamper1 = new PdfStamper(reader1, new FileOutputStream("D://intro.pdf"));
                PdfAnnotation link1 = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper1.getWriter(),
                    new Rectangle(136, 780, 559, 806), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
                    new PdfAction("D://introduction.pdf", 1));
                link1.setTitle("Click Here");
                stamper1.addAnnotation(link1, 2);
                stamper1.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the protocol. For web pages, your URI starts with `http://`; for files your URI should start with `file://`.

However, as the file you want to link to is also a PDF file, you probably don't want to use the `setAnchor()` method. You should use the `setRemoteGoto()` method instead. See the [MovieLinks2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=47) example.

If you want to add a link to an existing document, this is how to do it:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("hello.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("hello_link.pdf"));
PdfAnnotation link = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
    new Rectangle(36, 790, 559, 806), PdfAnnotation.HIGHLIGHT_INVERT,
    new PdfAction("hello.pdf", 1));
stamper.addAnnotation(link, 1);
stamper.close();
```

If you look inside the PDF document, you'll see that the new file named hello_link.pdf contains a Link annotation that refers to the old file hello.pdf:

[image]

Comment: imdb.setRemoteGoto("file:///D:/intro.pdf","1"); this also does not work

Comment: Er... either you use an URI with `setAnchor()` or you use a simple file path with `setRemoteGoto()`. Please take a look at the example and don't mix solutions.

Comment: Let me try this example.

Comment: if i am create new pdf then it work fine but not work in existing pdf

Comment: i have try this :Chunk page1 = new Chunk("separate document23213n");
         page1.setRemoteGoto("intro.pdf", 1);
   
 ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(page1), 10, 10, 0);

Comment: Please read chapter 7. You're doing it wrong. You need to create a link annotation (for instance using the `PdfAnnotation.createLink()` method) and add it to the existing document (for instance using the `PdfStamper.addAnnotation()` method.

Comment: This also does not work : ->                                   annotation = PdfAnnotation.createLink(stamper.getWriter(),
               new Rectangle(50f, 750f, 180f, 800f), aa,PdfAction.gotoRemotePage("intro.pdf","1", false, true));

Comment: i have try your code but it will not create hyper link. please dont take it as wrong.

Comment: i know PDFAction as well as addAnnotaion.

Comment: Check out the image I've added to the answer.

Comment: i did the same thing but link does not work. Thanks for guide

Comment: 1. Which version of iText did you use? 2. Are you testing this in Adobe Reader (your screen shot looks like pdf.js and that viewer doesn't support all the PDF functionality listed in ISO-32000-1).

Comment: Itext version 5.1.2 and i have tested in both adobe Reader as well as in browser but link does not work.

Comment: I'm using a more recent version. Maybe that's the reason for the discrepancy.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with iText version 2.1.0 :)

Comment: As documented, all versions predating 5 are considered outdated and as such no longer supported: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq